# Python3 + sqlite3 "LIKE" returns nothing

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am using python 3.8.10 and the module sqlite3. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS @ Kernel: 5.4.0-90-generic x86_64

I have a database with the structure:
`id` `INTEGER primary key` | `parent_id` `INTEGER` | `key` `TEXT` | `type` `INTEGER` | `value` `TEXT`. I can't edit the structure of the database nor am I allowed to change values in it. 
 Example record: 1250 | 1156 | TicketsLeft | 6 | 10

The code I'm using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3

TextA= 'TextInDb'
def query_named(key_in_db):
    con = sqlite3.connect("DBNAME.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key LIKE ?', ("%{}%".format(key_in_db),))
    records = cur.fetchall()
    print(records)
    for row in records:
        print(row)
    con.close()
    
    return records

print(query_named(TextA))
```

This returns:

 []
[]

Under Linux in python: 
When I do `'SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE id = 1234'` I get the corresponding result. 
But when I `'SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key LIKE "%SomeText%"'` it returns: `[]`.

##### Screenshots from DB Browser

Images: [DB Browser Link](https://ibb.co/dPCHMmc)
[Working SQL Code](https://ibb.co/vwKjyvy)

My aim is to get the ```value``` from a specific ```key``` so the placeholders % aren't really needed.

The prints are just for "debugging".
I'm clueless why it doesn't work although within a SQLite Browser I am able to get the result I'm looking for.

Thanks to the comment from @forpas here is a working solution:

```
#!usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3

TextA = 'SomeText'
def query_named(key_in_db):
    con = sqlite3.connect("DBNAME.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE TRIM(key) =  ?", (key_in_db,))
    records = cur.fetchall()
    print(records)
    for row in records:
        print(row)
    con.close()

    return records

print(query_named(TextA))
```

Due to the comments:

#### Test-Scenarious

`cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key LIKE ?', ("{}".format('TicketsLeft'),))` 
return:
[]
[]
[]
[]

`cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = ?', ('TicketsLeft',))` 
return: 
[]
[]

`cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = "TicketsLeft"')` 
return: 
 [] 
 []

`cur.execute("SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = 'TicketsLeft'")` 
return: 
 [] 
 []

`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE id = 1250")` 
return: 
 [('4',)] 
 ('4',) 
 [('4',)]

Comment: Your example row has `TicketsLeft`, so please include testing examples for that record.  What do the following return?  `cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key LIKE ?', ("%{}%".format('TicketsLeft'),))` or `cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = ?', ('TicketsLeft',))` or `cur.execute('SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = "TicketsLeft"')` or `cur.execute("SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key = 'TicketsLeft'")`

Comment: Then none of the rows, in the table being queried, contain that value.   What about `SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE id = 1250`?

Comment: @MatBailie This returns the right Value. Filtering by the ID works, but not by the key.

Comment: I want you to show the results to ***prove*** that the key is what you claim it is.

Comment: Try `cur.execute("SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE TRIM(key) =  ?", ('TicketsLeft',))`

Comment: @forpas this worked! I'm going to add the solution to the post.

Comment: This means that there are trailing spaces in the column. Update the table: `UPDATE DBNAME SET key = TRIM(key)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just haven't such record in your table. That may be some case-sensetive issue, I just copied your code and it works fine:

```sh
$ python d.py
[(None,)]
(None,)
[(None,)]

sqlite> select * from DBNAME;
1234||TextInDb||
```

Comment: I can select the record with the ID but when using the key that I just copied right from the database it does return [] so case-sensitivity and misspelling isn't the case here.

Comment: @Oxieth stupid question, did you copied correct column?..

Comment: Its not stupid as long as it helps. Yes, I copied the right column.

Comment: Did you try to execute that SELECT statement within `sqlite3` command or in SQLite Browser? (I'm not sure about last paragraph in your question)

Comment: Within Python, I'm not very familiar with sqlite3 command line.

Answer (score 0):

import sqlite3

TextA= 'TextInDb'

def query_named(key_in_db):

```
con = sqlite3.connect("DBNAME.db")

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT value FROM DBNAME WHERE key LIKE '%{}%'".format(key_in_db))

records = cur.fetchall()

print(records)
for row in records:
    print(row)
con.close()

return records
```

print(query_named(TextA))